# file/image upload to webserver using HttpPut() in android /java

Tags: java, android, https, httpwebrequest

i am new to android. i want to upload a file on my mobile phone to webserver using httpput ().
kindly help me with some snippets.

thanks in advance
jammy

Answer (score 0):

Android includes the standard java.net api. You can find lots of tutorials on the web about using it to upload files. You just have to be careful to do all your network communication on a non-UI thread.

Comment: It also contains the Apache Commons HTTP Client classes which are even more easier to use and there are lots of documentation available...